# Compiler rejects two identical template specializations

Tags: c++, templates, stl, typedef, template-specialization

I am using two helper structs to work with smart pointers and vectors

```
template<typename T>
struct Pointer {
    typedef shared_ptr<T> type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Vector {
    typedef vector<T, allocator<T>> type;
};
```

in this case is is obvious that the expression

```
is_same<
    vector<
        shared_ptr<T>,
        allocator<shared_ptr<T>>>,
    Vector<
        Pointer<T>::type>::type>
::value
```

yields true. However I have now a templated function (in fact an oparator) which is handled differently when using `Vector<Pointer<T>::type>::type` or the usual `vector`:

```
// (1) General version
template<typename T>
Foo& operator&(T& object);

// (2a) Specialized version
template<typename T>
Foo& operator&(vector<shared_ptr<T>, allocator<shared_ptr<T>>>& object);

// (2b) Specialized version which does not work
template<typename T>
Foo& operator&(typename Vector<typename Pointer<T>::type>::type& object);
```

Calling this operator when having (2a) in my code works as expected. However when I replace (2a) with (2b) then the compiler/linker tries to match the call with (1) which yields a link error for me as (1) is not defined/valid for vectors. Why is the compiler treating (2a) and (2b) differently?

Comment: Are those `typename`s nessecary in 2b?

Comment: You don't need to specify the `allocator` template argument to `vector`. It will by default be exactly as you declare it.

Comment: @jt234: IntelliSense and the compiler complain that without `typename` a `dependent name is not a type` and suggest me using the keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the compiler is unable to deduce the type in (2b). The problem is that it can match against

```
vector<shared_ptr<T>,allocator<shared_ptr<T>>>
```

because that is "just a type" to match against. For any given parameter, it just checks if there is a `T` and the type matches. There is only one option which the compiler has to test. For

```
typename Vector<typename Pointer<T>::type>::type
```

the compiler would have to try all `T` for with `Vector<...>::type` would yield to required type, which it does not do. That analysis, if at all possible, would be way more complex than just matching the direct type.

Comment: And by "way more complex", you mean "require solving the halting problem" (in the general case).  You can solve the OPs problem by explicitly passing in the `T` type.  Also note that this technique (dependent type arguments) is used to block template type deduction in a number of places (with an `typename identity<T>::type` argument), to force callers to pass in a type explicitly.

Comment: Is the problem just that I am searching for `Vector<Pointer<T>::type>::type` and not `Vector<T>::type`? I could still work with the last option but still the compiler complains. - Or let's change the question: is there definitely no way to match against my helper structs rather than the "pure" version of `vector` and `shared_ptr`?

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: No, the problem is that *anything* with `typename X::type` prevents `X` to be deduced, whatever it is. The problem is that the compiler just can't *try out* (or analyze) which `X` will be the correct one. In simple cases it might look that way to you, but there is no general solution and hence it's not allowed by the standard.

Comment: Ok, it will take some time to get used to this.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: the problem is called *non-deducible context*, in a nutshell I could do `template <> struct Pointer<int> { typedef int type; };` and `template <> struct Pointer<double> { typedef int type; };`, now if `Pointer<T>::type == int`, what's `T` ?